# Multipage Google Forms, point the respondent forward to a given page

Tags: google-apps-script, goto, google-forms

Would anyone please be so kind as to provide me with a working example of a GoogleApps script to generate a three-page Google Form, whose first ListItem question would contain page-number choices that would point the respondent to Page 2 or 3, with some questions already present on Pages 2 and 3? It seems perfectly possible to point to a deliberate page only when the pages are empty, but it does not work when questions are added on the pages.Having run into this problem, I have found two contributions on Stack Overflow (see below, including the code I also tried), where the problem remains unsolved, with answers limited to empty pages only.

Many thanks for a working piece of code.

[Google forms: Assign questions to Page Break and go to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827488/google-forms-assign-questions-to-page-break-and-go-to-page/27856293#27856293)

Comment: Your best chance to getting help would be to show what you tried and what problems you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it does not work when questions are added

...providing the code that didn't work for you is best, but
modifying my previous example you linked...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var title = 'GoToPage item example';
  var form = FormApp.create('My form example')

  // Create pages and items in order
  var item1 = form.addListItem().setTitle('First question');
  var page2 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Second page');
  var item2 = form.addListItem().setTitle('Second question')
  var page3 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Third page');
  var item3 = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Third question')

  // Now set item choices
  item1.setChoices([
     item1.createChoice('Choice 1',page2),
     item1.createChoice('Choice 2',page3)
   ]);

   item2.setChoices([
     item2.createChoice('Choice 3',page3),
     item2.createChoice('Choice 4',FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)
   ]);
}
```